# Sublime Text shows "NUL" characters in build output

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, red, sublime-build

I've coded a simple Red "Hello world" program in Sublime Text 3:

```
Red []

print "Hello world!"
```

I've also created a build system that I'm trying to use to compile and run the program, where `G:\Red Programming Language\redlang.exe` is the Red programming language compiler that I downloaded from the Windows link [here](http://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html):

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "\"G:\\Red Programming Language\\redlang\" \"$file\""
}
```

The problem is that whenever I use my build system on a saved program, a strange `NUL` character appears between each character of the build output:

[image: Screenshot]

This doesn't happen with any other build system I have installed. The output appears fine if I run the `redlang.exe` from the Command Prompt, so it's probably an issue with my Sublime Text setup; I'm using Sublime Text Build 3083 and Windows 10. How can I get rid of those `NUL` characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of Red programs on Windows is using the native UTF-16LE encoding, which is the cause of the NUL characters you are seeing, as Sublime's output capturing defaults to UTF-8. You need to change it in your build system using the `encoding` command as described in the Sublime build system [documentation](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html).

So you might try something like:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "\"G:\\Red Programming Language\\redlang\" \"$file\"",
    "encoding": "UTF-16LE"
}
```

See the supported encodings list [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). Hope this helps.